# CAS redirection with wrong path

Tags: java, servlet-filters, cas

I'm trying to deploy a CAS server and a client.
First, there is my config in deployerConfigContext.xml on CAS server :

```
<bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService">
    <property name="id" value="1" />
    <property name="name" value="HTTP and IMAP on localhost:8080/firstCasClient" />
    <property name="description" value="Allows HTTP(S) and IMAP(S) protocols on localhost:8080/firstCasClient" />
    <property name="serviceId" value="^(https?|imaps?)://([A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.)*localhost:8080/firstCasClient/*" />
    <property name="evaluationOrder" value="0" />
</bean>
```

On my client, I use filters like this :

```
<!-- CAS -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8888/cas-server-webapp-3.5.2/login</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>serverName</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8080/firstCasClient</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8888/cas-server-webapp-3.5.2</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>serverName</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8080/firstCasClient</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

So when I go to `http://localhost:8080/firstCasClient/`, It works fine, I come to CAS authenticate page.
But after good authenticate, CAS redirect me to this url :

```
http://localhost:8080/firstCasClient/firstCasClient/firstCasClient/
```

I doesn't understand why, so I came to ask you some help.
I hope someone could help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found the solution.

I replaced this lines :

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>serverName</param-name>
    <param-value>http://localhost:8080/firstCasClient</param-value>
</init-param>
```

by :

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>service</param-name>
    <param-value>http://localhost:8080/firstCasClient</param-value>
</init-param>
```

in CAS `Authentication Filter` and `CAS Validation Filter`

Then it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also replace

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>serverName</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080/firstCasClient</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

with

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>serverName</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080/</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

If you specifiy `serverName` you only need to provide the server name not the whole path.